# load password protected swfs

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

Today, we can create password protected swfs using various content generation tools. When the user opens that swf, he/she needs to enter a password, and only then the encrypted swf can be viewed.

Now, I am trying to load one such encrypted swf in a flex based AIR application, and I am using the SWFLoader class for that. But instead of the user entering the password, I want the application to provide the password at the time of loading the swf. Is this even possible? I tried googling, but nothing came up.

Any help would be really appreciated.

-- Kapil

Answer (score 0):

Is the prompt for the password implemented in the .swf you are loading ?

I would think that what you need to do is modify your protection software to accept variables in a more automated way without a dialog box. For example when it loads it might go into a wait state, waiting for your air app that's loaded it to feed it the password. Or it might accept a parameter string.

If you did this, your Air app could store the passwords and just pass that data to the .swf it loads. Not sure how your password protection works, but I think that's where you'd want to focus your efforts. To help better, I'd really have to know a little more about the specifics.

Comment: Hi Prototypical....thanks for the response. Actually, I was using a standard tool such as "Adobe Captivate" to generate the protected swf. As you can see, there is no way I can modify this software to generate the kind of swf you mentioned. I was thinking whether there are some standards in creating protected swf files, and if I could use them to load the required file without prompting the user.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have knowledge of Captivate.But it'd be worthwhile to add that detail to the question.